# watchPosition not working correctly by using ngroute (Timeout, code 3)

Tags: angularjs, geolocation, timeout, angularjs-ng-route

I use `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` to find out the current location insight an angularJS application. That works well.
Now i added the `ngRoute` functionality to the page.

Starting the application redirects the user to `#/main` where a controller gets the current position an displays this position on an map.
That still works.
This is the controller:

```
MyMapCtrl.controller('watchPosMap', ['$scope', 'MarkerService', function($scope) {
    $scope.ha = true;
    $scope.timeout = 20000;

    $scope.processNewLocation = function (data) {
                 [..code to process an display the location ...]
    };

    $scope.watchMyPositionChangesID = 
        navigator.geolocation
                  .watchPosition(
                      function(data) {
                          $scope.processNewLocation(data);
                      },
                      function(e){
                          $scope.errorMsg = e;
                          if (e.code == 2)
                          {alert('Unable to detect location');}

                      },
                      { enableHighAccuracy: true,timeout: $scope.timeout }); 

}]);
```

The Problem is: if the application goes to an different route (like from `#/main` to `#/detail`) an than back to the main route, the map is displayed, but the geolocation seams not to work.
The line `$scope.processNewLocation(data)` is not executed anymore.

While debugging that situation I found out, that `$scope.watchMyPositionChangesID` is lost after returning to  `#/main`, `navigator.geolocation` is called again, but results in an timeout. So `$scope.processNewLocation(data);` is not called again, the `watchPosition`results in timeout (Code 3)

http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#position_error_interface

So no new position-object could successfully acquired.

I have no idea way?!

//Update: 
It seams to work, if I remove the "geolocation-watch-objekt" by using `navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(id);`.
The problem is: how to determine the `id` outside the `watchPosMap`-controller? I think fetching the angular-element is not an elegant idea, right? Should I pass the watchID as an parameter to the new route/view/controller?

//Update 2:
I added to the `watchPosMap` - controller an `$routeChangeStart` listener in order to remove the `watchPosition` object, if the route changed.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current) { 
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch($scope.watchMyPositionChangesID);
});
```

Is that best practice?